# multiple testng test listeners running using gradle test command

Tags: gradle, testng, listeners

I have 2 custom listeners implementing ITestListener, ISuiteListener, IInvokedMethodListener . when I run the command from gradle as gradle clean --test testname . it runs both listeners though I have only one class defined in the @Listeners annotation in test. Its a gradle project but when I run the test in intellij as testng test it runs with only 1 listener as expected. Can you please tell how to make it run with only 1 listener using gradle command
my build.gradle below and testng version I am using is 6.9.4 and I tried 6.9.10 too

```
ext {
        unitTestingMinHeapSize = "512m"
}
// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
// Apply the application plugin to add support for building an application
apply plugin: 'application'
// Apply the eclipse plugin to add support for building on eclipse
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
// Apply the idea plugin to add support for building on IDEA
apply plugin: 'idea'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.

    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
        compile project(':oos')
        testCompile project(':oos')
        compile "commons-pool:commons-pool:$apacheCommonsPool1Version"
        compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$apacheCommonsLangVersion"
        compile "org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:$apacheCommonsPool2Version"
        compile "com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:$rabbitMQClientVersion"
        compile "redis.clients:jedis:$jedisVersion"
        compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:$httpClientVersion"
        compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:$httpmimeversion"
        compile "io.rest-assured:rest-assured:$restAssuredVersion"
        compile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$hamcrestVersion"
        compile "org.postgresql:postgresql:$postgresqlversion"
        compile "com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1"
        compile "com.codepine.api:testrail-api-java-client:1.0.2"
        testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$mockitoVersion"
        testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion"
        compile ("org.testng:testng:$testngVersion") {
                exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
        }
        testCompile "org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:$apacheCommonsPool2Version"

}

test {

        for (String key : System.getProperties().keySet()) {
                systemProperty key, System.properties["$key"]
        }

        jvmArgs "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"
        systemProperty "runId", findProperty("runId")

        useTestNG { useDefaultListeners = true }

        beforeTest { descriptor ->
                logger.lifecycle("Running: " + descriptor)
        }

        minHeapSize = "$unitTestingMinHeapSize"
        jvmArgs '-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC', '-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode' //,'-XX:+PrintGCDetails','-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps'
        if (System.getProperty("test.profile", "false").equals("true")) {
                jvmArgs "-noverify", "-agentpath:${profilerDir}/lib/deployed/jdk16/mac/libprofilerinterface.jnilib=${profilerDir}/lib,5140,0"
        }
        // listen to standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s)
        onOutput { descriptor, event ->
                // logger.lifecycle("Test: " + descriptor + " produced standard out/err: " + event.message )
                if (event.destination == TestOutputEvent.Destination.StdErr) {
                        logger.error("  ERROR: " + event.message.trim())
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: What version of TestNG are you working with ? Can you also please help share your `build.gradle` file  (You can update your question with the contents)

Comment: please see the build.gradle and testng version in contents of question